# Shouldn't the product of all $n$-th roots of unity be $1$?

Tags: complex-numbers

nth root of unity:

$$
1^{1/n} = e^{i2\pi k/n}\ \ \ \ k=0,1,...,n-1
$$

multiplying together all the nth roots of unit to get back "1":

$$
1=\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}e^{i\left(2\pi k/n\right)}
$$

for n=2:

$$
1=\left(e^{i2\pi\left(0\right)/2}\right)\left(e^{i2\pi\left(1\right)/2}\right) \\
1=\left(1\right)\left(-1\right) \\
1=\ -1
$$

**why is 1 = -1?**

For n=4:

$$
1=\left(e^{i2\pi\left(0\right)/4}\right)\left(e^{i2\pi\left(1\right)/4}\right)\left(e^{i2\pi\left(2\right)/4}\right)\left(e^{i2\pi\left(3\right)/4}\right) \\
1=\left(1\right)\left(i\right)\left(-1\right)\left(-i\right) \\
1=\ -1
$$

**why is 1 = -1? shouldn't it be "1"?**

A few definitions:

$$
e^{i\theta} = cos(\theta) + i sin(\theta)
$$

$$
e^{-i\theta} = cos(\theta) - i sin(\theta)
$$

$$
i*i = -1
$$

$$
\frac{1}{i} = -i
$$

Comment: You seem to have determined that the initial "equality" is sometimes false. Indeed, the product of the $n$-th roots of unity isn't always unity.

Comment: I'm just finding all the nth roots of unity and multiplying them together... to undo the nth root...  1 =($1^{1/n}$ first-root)*($1^{1/n}$ second_root)…*($1^{1/n}$ nth_root)$

Comment: *"I'm just finding all the nth roots of unity and multiplying them together"* ... That's as good a way to spend an evening as any, but ... Who told you that you'd get $1$ as the result? You've shown for yourself that this simply isn't true, even for $n=2$. To ensure that you get $1$ from an $n$-th root of unity, you take the product *of $n$ copies of that root*.

Comment: its that what taking the nth-root of something does?  example: sqrt(2) * sqrt(2) = 2.  the reason, is i'm missing something... why doesn't it work...

Comment: In $\sqrt{2}\cdot \sqrt{2}=2$ (or $(-\sqrt{2})\cdot(-\sqrt{2})=2$), you're multiplying *a particular square root of $2$* by itself, getting $2$; *that* is what square roots do. But if you multiply the *two different* square roots of two together, you get $\sqrt{2}\cdot(-\sqrt{2})=-2 \neq 2$.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HhlD7sX5Tp8

Comment: I don't have time to watch a six-minute video to find the source of your confusion. Can you provide a time stamp?

Comment: Dane's right.  its $x^2-2=\left(x-e^{i2\pi\left(0\right)/2}\right)\left(x-e^{i2\pi\left(1\right)/2}\right)$  silly me.

Comment: (You either meant $x^2-1$, or else you omitted some $\sqrt{2}$s in your factors, but be that as it may ...) I'm happy that someone got through to you. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $n$th roots of unity are the roots of the polynomial $x^n - 1$.

If you factor this polynomial as
$$x^n - 1 = \prod_{j=0}^{n-1} (x-e^{2\pi i j/n}) ,$$
then you will notice by multiplying out and comparing constant terms that the product of the roots is $\pm 1$, with the sign depending on whether $n$ is even or odd.

Comment: For those that don't know, this is precisely the implication of [Vieta's Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas) for the constant term.

Answer (score 2):

Clearly the original claim is false.

Roots of unity come in two types: the real ones, and the pairs of complex conjugates.  The complex conjugates, being of unit modulus, give pairwise products of $1$.  That leaves the real roots.  For an odd index like cube roots there is just the real root $1$, which when multiplied by all those complex conjugate pairs still gives $1$. But for even indices like square or fourth roots, there's that other real root $-1$.  That's when the overall product becomes $-1$, too.